# Все перепробовал, не работает функция IF

Tags: javascript

```js
var zmazanie

function shuffle() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}
var stvorci = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
stvorci.sort(shuffle);
console.log(stvorci);
var b = 0.5;

function zmaz(stvorci) {
  if (stvorci[0] > b) {
    zmazanie = stvorci.shift();
  } else {
    zmazanie = stvorci.pop();
  }
};
console.log(stvorci);
```

Comment: Что это такое, и где *функция* `IF`?

Comment: Это js, функция if в третьем абзаце

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. Что должна делать функция `zmaz`, которую Вы не вызываете?

Comment: Я создал поле с числами от нуля до шестнадцати, у меня задача перемешать все числа и выкинуть из этого поля одно рандомное число, кроме нуля. Написал для этого If, который проверяет является ли первое число нулем, если нет, он удаляет первое число, если да, то удаляет последнее. И теперь не могу понять, почему у меня не работает if.

Comment: Просто, учусь в Словакии, zmazat' - типо, удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И теперь не могу понять, почему у меня не работает if.

Потому что Вы не вызываете функцию, в которой находится `if`.

```js
var zmazanie

function shuffle() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}
var stvorci = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
stvorci.sort(shuffle);
console.log(JSON.stringify(stvorci));

var b = 0.5;
function zmaz(stvorci) {
  if (stvorci[0] > b) {
    zmazanie = stvorci.shift();
  } else {
    zmazanie = stvorci.pop();
  }
};
zmaz(stvorci);
console.log(JSON.stringify(stvorci));
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.

Comment: @MaksimZhilin Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.